# Contract red flags - to sign or not to sign?

Tags: new-job, united-kingdom, contracts, legal

*update* Thank you all so much! I consulted a lawyer about the contract and he said not to touch it with a flamethrower. I'll keep looking for something else!

I need to quit my digital project manager role (UK) due to being treated horrendously by new employers during probation, but have been offered a well paid job as a product owner fairly quickly. It's with a telecoms/utilities firm and they didn't really ask me many questions about my competency so I'm already a little wary about it.

However, I've just had the contract through and now I'm very wary about it despite reassurances from the recruiter. It includes things like:

- they can make me see their own medical professional who will report back to them
- I can't work in any related field (telecoms/utilities? IT? Unclear) for nine months if I leave
- Hours (although flexible) are 9-6, not 9-5, with lunch being unpaid (my kid's nursery hours are 8-6 and the commute is often over half an hour at peak times)
- No paid sick leave period at all
- Pension is just 2%
- I can't do paid work anywhere else, even in unrelated fields

I've not worked in telecommunications/utilities before, so I'm really not sure how normal all this is. The vast majority of their workforce is very young and working in a call centre and I suspect I'm under the same contract.

I'm unhappy with it. Do I trust them and sign, or do I face unemployment and penury?

Comment: Unfortunately, we can’t make the decision for you. If you really want the job, you should talk to the prospective employer about your concerns.

Comment: "due to being treated horrendously by new employers during probation" - who's probation? Theirs or your?

Comment: In the UK lunch break is mandated (20 mins uninterrupted) but doesn't have to be paid. For example in my previous role I was paid for 7.5 hours every day although I did a normal 8 hour day. See [this page](https://www.gov.uk/rest-breaks-work) for more on breaks

Comment: Disclosure of medical records: [Generally up to the doctor](https://www.tuc.org.uk/research-analysis/reports/confidentiality-and-medical-records) but their guidance is to seek your consent first. Unsure if your signing the contract implies consent. Ask a lawyer on this one

Comment: Non-complete clauses: Generally BS. They can't force you to stay unemployed; if they don't want you working for someone else, they should pay you. See [reasonable restrictions](https://businessadvice.co.uk/insurance/liability-and-indemnity/when-are-non-compete-clauses-enforceable/) and consult a laywer

Comment: Sick pay: UK has statuatory sick pay and sick days are generally taken as needed. See [gov.uk](https://www.gov.uk/browse/working/time-off) for more

Comment: Industry: Call centers are usually high turnover toxic places. I'm not surprised to see a predatory contract from them. If I really needed to put food on the table, I would take the job and leave as soon as something else came in. I would also ignore the non-compete BS. But that would've been my decision, not yours

Comment: What sort of telco is this is it some small second tier reseller?  The big mobile and telecoms companies will normally have better than SSSP and 2% is the minimum legal requirement . I would suggest joining Prospect or the CWU (dependant on your grade)

Answer (score 3):

I can't tell you whether or not you should take the job.  However, here are some things you can do to get some more information that can help you make that decision:

1. Ask them the questions you have about the contract.  They should be more than happy to explain what their non-compete covers (according to them, at least), what the purpose of the medical official is and what they will require that person to report to them, and so on
2. Look at reviews of the company on sites like glassdoor (I have no affiliation to them, it's just the most well-known)
3. Since you have a kid, ask if you can work 8:30-5 with a half hour lunch instead, or come to some other arrangement like working a shorter day in the office and teleworking in the evening

Once you have all this information, you can make a more informed decision whether you want to take the job, or wait for a better offer.  Keep in mind that everything is negotiable, you just have to be willing to walk away.

Comment: As this is the UK yo have the right to request flexible working

Answer (score 0):

The non-compete clause: Don't sign it. Strike through on your contract. There is no good reason for them to not want you to work in the industry. Even not working for a competitor wouldn't be acceptable if you are in a generic industry and the competitor doesn't gain an unfair advantage hiring you instead of someone else.

For the rest: Take the whole package and see what it's worth. Which means the salary must be a good chunk better than what you would get elsewhere, because the rest is not too good. And of course you should discuss the time. It seems to be 8 hours plus 1 hour lunch. If you can do with 1/2 hour lunch then talk to them and see how flexible they are.